# Finding the temperature of Earth from temperature of Mars and its distance from Sun

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astronomy, temperature, planets, solar-system

I am to compute the temperature of planet--in fact I've already found out it's Earth--knowing only:

1. the surface temperature of Mars (210 K) and its distance from Sun (1.524 AU)
2. and of course distance of Earth from Sun (1 AU).

I have no data concerning the temperature of Sun, surfaces of the planet, etc. What formula should I use? Thank you.

Comment: The Apostrophe Police shudder in horror.

Comment: What Carl means is that "it's" means "it is" so "and it's distance" means "and it is distance." You want "its" which is the possessive.

Comment: yes, you're right. sorry and thanks for the edition

Comment: Temperature of a planet also depends upon its atmosphere...

Comment: SachinShekhar refers to the [albedo of the planets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_albedo), but both planets have roughly the same value. A hint on how to solve this would be to use the [inverse square law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law).

Comment: The inverse square law is only part of the answer. You need to compare that equation with the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan–Boltzmann_law).